# Riemann-Stieltjes integral and discontinuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is discontinuous at some point of the interval, there exists a monotone increasing function g such that f is not g-integrable.

Is this true? I've been thinking how to construct g, but haven't been able to come up with an answer.

Any hints?

Comment: As proved below, just take any increasing $g$ which has a jump discontinuity at the same point were $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riemann-Stieltjes integral does not exist if $f$ and $g$ share a common discontinuity point.

Suppose $g$ is monotone increasing and WLOG $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous from the right at $\xi \in (a,b).$

Now consider any partition $P = (x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1},\xi, x_i, \ldots, x_n)$ with $\xi$ as a partition point and $x_i - \xi = \delta_i$

There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ (including $\delta_i$), there are points $y_1, y_2 \in (\xi, \xi + \delta)$ such that $|f(y_1) - f(\xi)| \geqslant \epsilon$ and  $|g(y_2) - g(\xi)| \geqslant \epsilon$.

Then

$$U(P,f,g) - L(P,f,g) \geqslant \epsilon^2,$$

since $g(x_i) - g(\xi) \geqslant g(y_2) - g(\xi) \geqslant \epsilon$ and $\sup_{x \in [\xi,x_i]} f(x) - \inf_{x \in [\xi,x_i]}  f(x) \geqslant \epsilon$

Hence, the Riemann criterion is not satisfied and $f$ is not RS integrable with respect to $g$ on $[a,b]$.